# asp button does not fire event

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am responsible to maintain web application of others. The application is developed by MVC Framework. In view module, it has some file which can submit data by using button event. However, it does not work. So, I try to start new MVC application in order to find out how to solve the problem. But, I can find none. The following is sample code. Could you please suggest me how to enable button event? I am not sure that can I use this technique in MVC application.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<script runat="server">
    Public Sub submit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        lbl1.Text = "Your name is " & txt1.Text
    End Sub
</script>

<asp:Content ID="aboutTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    About Us
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="aboutContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <p>
        Put content here.
    </p>
        <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        Enter your name:
        <asp:TextBox id="txt1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="submit" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClieintClick="submit" />
        <p><asp:Label id="lbl1" runat="server" /></p>
        </form>
</asp:Content>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `action="YourActionName"` in your `form` element. For instance like:

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server" action="YourActionName">
```

or

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" action='<%= Url.Action("YourActionName") %>'>
```

Also, there is a spelling mistake in the following loc:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="submit" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClieintClick="submit" />

OnClieintClick//
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using MVC code in your application but rather Web Forms. You should really check out [asp.net/mvc](http://asp.net/mvc) to get started.

Comment: I think so. However, it is the way the lagacy system does. It will be very difficult to change them. Do you have any suggestion to deal with this?

Comment: If the legacy system is is mixing webforms code with MVC code the best advice I couuld give to you is to refactor now. Don't continue building on a broken system as it will only cause more problems down the line. Rebuild properly no in MVC.